# Brocard's theorem - $O$ is orthocenter of $\Delta EFI$

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, circles, geometric-transformation

> Consider  $ABCD$ is cyclic quadrilateral, the intersection of $AD$ and $CB$ is $E$, $AB$, $CD$ is $F$; $AC$ and  $BD$ is $I$. Prove that $O$ is  orthocenter of $\Delta EFI$.

---

[image]

Firstly, i will prove $OI\perp EF$.

Then i have $IK$ and $KF$ is bisector of $\angle BKD$ so $KF\perp IK$

But i need to prove $K;I;O$ are collinear , i am stuck here. Help me to continue and give me some another way, thanks.

Comment: Do you know what polar is?

Comment: @greedoid: I don't know, have you got another idea ?

Comment: Well, I suggest you study it first, it is a powerful toll.

Comment: Do you know inversion?

Comment: Yes, a little..you can use it and i will try researching

Comment: See https://imomath.com/index.php?options=334 , Theorem 9

Comment: An old Kvant magazine article about pole and polar line containing Brocard's theorem with proof (non-English but perhaps even just the pictures can be useful): http://kvant.mccme.ru/1986/07/polyus_i_polyara_otnositelno_o.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, say we have an inversion with respect to circle $C$ with center at $O$ and radius $r$.

Say we have an arbitrary point $P$ and let $P'$ be it image. Then line orthogonal to $PO$ through $P'$ is *a polar line* for (*pole*) $P$.

From definition we see that polar line is orthogonal to $OP$ and it is relatively easy to prove that if $A$ is on polar for $B$ then $B$ is on polar for $A$.

Also, there is a theorem (which is harder to prove, but again not so hard, just use of the power of the point) which says: however we take two points $X,Y$ from set $\{E,F,I\}$ then line $XY$ is polar for the third point.

Now you can easly prove your statement.

---

Edit:

Since $EF$ is polar line for $I$ we have $IO\bot EF$

Since $EI$ is polar line for $F$ we have $FO\bot EI$

Since $FI$ is polar line for $E$ we have $EO\bot FI$

So, $IO,EO$ and $FO$ are altitudes in triangle $EFI$ ...

Comment: How can i solve it by polar?

Comment: See https://imomath.com/index.php?options=334 , Theorem 7